# RPScreenRecorder startCaptureWithHandler: not returning microphone sound in sample handler

Tags: objective-c, microphone, rpscreenrecorder

I am trying to use RPScreenRecorder startCaptureWithHandler:completionHandler: api on my iPad with iOS 11.4 to grab audio and video directly. It works well with the app screen, app audio and the camera, but when I turn on the microphone using microphoneEnabled = YES, I never get any audio sample for the mic in the callback.

I added the microphone privacy usage key in the info.plist but that did not help.

I am not sure what I can do next to try to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This code gets me audio buffers containing actual microphone audio (even without a microphone usage string or audio session configuration):

```
RPScreenRecorder *recorder = [RPScreenRecorder sharedRecorder];

recorder.microphoneEnabled = YES;

[recorder startCaptureWithHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer, RPSampleBufferType bufferType, NSError* error) {
    NSLog(@"Capture %@, %li, %@", sampleBuffer, (long)bufferType, error);
    if (RPSampleBufferTypeAudioMic == bufferType) {
        // Do something with mic audio
    }
} completionHandler:^(NSError* error) {
    NSLog(@"startCapture: %@", error);
}];
```

There's a permission dialog that asks whether you Allow Screen & Microphone, Allow Screen Only, or don't allow. Is it possible you tapped screen-only? N.B. I don't know how to reset this dialog.

The other possibility is that you're setting `microphoneEnabled` *after* you start capturing? That might not work. Nah, that works for me too.

**Previous guess**

You might need to activate a recording `AVAudioSession`:

```
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord)  // or AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord!
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just added

`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];`
`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error:nil];`

but that did not help. :(

Comment: Are you sure it's mic audio and not app audio that you are getting in the callback? I tried to hack the Fox game demo and I got the same issue, no mic audio but I get the game audio fine.

Comment: Yes, `bufferType` is `RPSampleBufferTypeAudioMic`, I write the sample buffers to a file and I can hear myself. This is with no microphone description, no audio session configuration.  iPhoneX/11.2.5. Not sure what the fox game demo is.

Comment: Here's a repo that shows the code that works for me: https://github.com/rfistman/RPScreenRecorder

Comment: That sample doesn't work for me. I don't have the audio from the mic. I think it might just be something on my device.

I will try to get access to another device to see if it is just mine.

Comment: So after resetting my ipad, it now works fine. No idea why it failed before.
Thanks for helping me @Rhythmic Fistman.

Comment: Sounds like some background process got constipated. All’s well that ends well.

Comment: Rebooting is the solution.