# ReplayKit: RPScreenRecorder.shared().startCapture() NOT WORKING

Tags: swift, avfoundation, video-recording, avkit, replaykit

`ReplayKit` has really been frustrating me recently. For some reason

```
RPScreenRecorder.shared().startCapture(handler: { (sample, bufferType, error) in
```

does not actually work when I call it because I have a `print()` statement inside it and it is never called.

My code in the `ViewController` is:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import SpriteKit
import ReplayKit
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, RPPreviewViewControllerDelegate {

    var assetWriter:AVAssetWriter!
    var videoInput:AVAssetWriterInput!

func startRecording(withFileName fileName: String) {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *)
        {

            assetWriter = try! AVAssetWriter(outputURL: fileURL, fileType:
                AVFileType.mp4)
            let videoOutputSettings: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
                AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.h264,
                AVVideoWidthKey : UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width,
                AVVideoHeightKey : UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
            ];

            videoInput  = AVAssetWriterInput (mediaType: AVMediaType.video, outputSettings: videoOutputSettings)
            videoInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
            assetWriter.add(videoInput)
            print("HERE")
            RPScreenRecorder.shared().startCapture(handler: { (sample, bufferType, error) in
                print("RECORDING")
            }
      }
}

func stopRecording(handler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void)
    {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *)
        {
            RPScreenRecorder.shared().stopCapture
                {    (error) in
                    handler(error)
                    self.assetWriter.finishWriting
                        {
                            print("STOPPED")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

"HERE" is printed, but not "RECORDING"

[p.s. sorry for bad formatting in code, I'm sure you'll understand :)]

---

I have also tried a different method:

```
let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()
recorder.startRecording{ [unowned self] (error) in
    guard error == nil else {
        print("There was an error starting the recording.")
        return
    }
    print("Started Recording Successfully")
 }
```

and to stop the recording...

```
    recorder.stopRecording { [unowned self] (preview, error) in
        print("Stopped recording")
        guard preview != nil else {
            print("Preview controller is not available.")
            return
        }
        onGoingScene = true
        preview?.previewControllerDelegate = self
        self.present(preview!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

This method does not stop when I call the recorder.stopRecording() function, "Stopped recording" is never called.

---

Can someone please help me because this is really frustrating me, how can you PROPERLY use `ReplayKit` to record your screen in iOS 11? I have searched all over the internet and none of the methods work for me, I don't why. P.S. I have the necessary permission keys in my Info.plist.

Thanks

Comment: Your "RECORDING" message prints fine for me _once I hit the Allow Screen Recording" in the privacy dialog_. This is on iPhoneX/11.2.5. There was a similar problem here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50936353/22147 which was fixed by a device restart.

Comment: Also, as a side note; replay kit does not work in simulator.

Answer (score 7):

A huge reminder that ReplayKit doesn't work in simulator. I wasted hours on the exact same issue until realized that ReplayKit will never trigger startCapture handler because it never records in simulator.

Comment: Still seems to be the case in 2023, strange that it doesn't even print an error about it.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are quite few possible causes for this issue.
Some of them are here:

1. Your Replay kit Shared Recorder might be crashed, **For that you can restart your device and check again.**
2. There might be printable issue in your replay kit. For that kindly conform to the `RPScreenRecorderDelegate`Protocol and add `Recording Changes
   screenRecorder:didStopRecordingWithPreviewViewController:error:`
   method to your class and check if any error shows up in this method.